# Application Debugging is disabled in Visual Studio 2012 on Classic ASP Debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, asp-classic, iis-express

I'd like to debug `Classic ASP` website at `Visual Studio 2012` with `IIS Express`. Hence, I attached the `iisexpress.exe` in `VS 2012`, but it shows `Application Debugging is disabled`. What could be a problem ? Do I want to enable any configuration settings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have visual studio 2012 to test it on as far as I know visual studio cannot debug asp classic code natively.
The way I debug my asp classic code is to put in stop statements on the line above the one I want to debug
[like this post says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2005/06/24/432308.aspx). the break point is just typing in stop.

```
function DoDate(inp)
   stop
if isnull(inp) then
    DoDate = "Never"
    exit function
end if
```

In the above example the page when loaded will stop at the breakpoint and pop up a dialog asking if you would like to debug it, you can then step through the function and even see variables like you normally would.

note: The link says visual studio 2005 but it also works in 2010(and should also work in 2012), you also do not need the DEBUG extension.

also ensure you have server side debugging activated in IIS or this will not work.

Comment: VS2012 can debug Classic ASP code natively using both full fat IIS and IIS Express.

Comment: @user2255811 Your answer saved me, I spent a lot of time make it work. Finally, Stop make a trick. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

First of all you need to enable server side debugging of classic ASP script. Do this by running the following commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set config "[YOUR_SITE_NAME]" -section:system.webServer/asp /appAllowClientDebug:"True" /appAllowDebugging:"True"  /commit:apphost
```

Where `[YOUR_SITE_NAME]` is the name of your website. You can find this name by opening up:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

...and searching for your site.

Next, start an IIS Express instance from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:c:\users\kevin\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config /site:"[YOUR_SITE_NAME]" /apppool:"Clr2IntegratedAppPool"
```

Again, `[YOUR_SITE_NAME]` is the name of your IIS Express website.

Then attach Visual Studio 2012's debugger and set a breakpoint in the script you wish to debug. Browse to your site/script and your should see the breakpoint light up:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and helpful. But, when I attach the IISExpress just it shows blank screen, which is not bring the files for debugging. If I put stop in asp coding it loaded all the files for debugging. Please advise what is the reason for this strange behaviour ?

Comment: Did you add the script you wish to debug to your solution? You need to do that and set a breakpoint.

Comment: +1 This worked!  ... For a small set of my project/site's ASP files.  Can you take a look at [this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38937879/2662901)?

Answer (score 3):

Go to IIS-->ASP-->Debugging properties -->enable client and server side debugging

then attach w3wp process from VS2012

Answer (score 0):

I like using Full-blown IIS on my dev machine as it's what my web servers run and have had problems with differences between Casini and IIS in the past..

Anyway, I was unable to do it the way that @Kev suggested.  I did some more playing around + reading and found that on the "Attach To Process" window, you need to specifically select "Script Code" in the "Attach To:" option.

```
1) F9 to set breakpoints in code
2) Ctrl-Alt-P to attach to process
3) Next to "Attach To:" click on the "Select" button
4) Select "Script Code"
5) In my case, attach to "w3wp.exe"
```

Enjoy debugging your code.

Comment: Hello, I tried this - and while it does stop at my breakpoints, i can't see the values of anything. Mousing over any of the variables does nothing.  Any suggestions? This is on IIS 8.5 (win 8.1) and vs 2012.

Comment: Hmmm....  I haven't see this before..  occasionally the ide has issues like where you mouse-over and see no values.  this is usually fixed by moving the mouse away from your variable and then back.  Other than that, you could use the Watch window or the Immediate window.  Not quite as convenient, but usually still workable. or even Ctrl-F9 (??) for Quick Watch.

Comment: Try highlighting the variable (double-clicking it should highlight it) and then hover over it. I also thought I couldn't hover over variables and see their values, but then I highlighted (selected the text with the mouse) and hovered over it and it worked.