# Attached to Process only shows an empty solution and files list are missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp-classic, iis-express

I've attached a `IISEXPRESS.EXE` process at `Visual Studio 2012` even though it doesn't list out the Classic ASP file for debugging. It only shows an empty solution file. what would be a problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application Debugging is disabled in Visual Studio 2012 on Classic ASP Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760878/application-debugging-is-disabled-in-visual-studio-2012-on-classic-asp-debugging)

Answer (score 1):

May be some thing to do with 32 bit app mode. Happened to me once when using classic asp on iis-7.5 Please try [How can I force IIS Express to run in 32 bit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226582/how-can-i-force-iis-express-to-run-in-32-bit-mode) this to run in 32 bit mode