# Debugging server-side ASP classic in VS 2012

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, asp-classic, iis-express

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761926/2662901) I am able to connect to an IIS Express instance with debugging.

However, I am only able to place breakpoints in a small set of my ASP pages, as shown in the VS2012 Solution Explorer while the debugger is attached to the website's IIS Express process:

[image: VS2012 screenshot]

These are basically the first ~20 ASP files in the site's directory hierarchy.

If I try to put a breakpoint in any other ASP file in the solution I get a tooltip message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

How do can I enable breakpoint debugging in *all* ASP files in the website?

Comment: are you adding breakpoints with VS running ? This may cause this kind of error. If yes, please, try stop VS, set all breakpoints and then try again. If no, let us know. And please, check if you are running in debug mode and your webconfig file is set to debug.

Comment: @RodrigoCelebrone - Yes, it's debug mode and `web.config` has `<compilation debug="true"/>`.  It doesn't matter whether the breakpoints are set before or while running: They work in the files shown, and don't in the files not shown.  I have, however, noticed that I can get the debugger to load a file it doesn't automatically by putting a `STOP` statement in it.  At that point I can dynamically place breakpoints.

Comment: @feetwet web.config has absolutely nothing to do with clasic asp so Setting compilation to anything has absolutely no effect on classic asp it is for asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `STOP` keyword in classic ASP.  Wherever you write this in VBS code the server will stop and prompt you to attach a Visual Studio debugger, which will then give you full visibility into the running source file.

In order to do this you need to [configure IIS to allow Server side Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761926/2662901).